# In Grid want to add ajax pagination

Tags: ajax, pagination

I have grid at admin section. I want to add ajax-pagination to stop reloading page. Any way code or module to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading product view in category list with AJAX](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/loading-product-view-in-category-list-with-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the module, search for "ajax scroll", "infinite scroll" or "ajax pager" at the connect.

Comment: I just want change page without reloading page in Grid List. Will it work as per expectation?

Answer (score 1):

A javascript solution, although not the best approach, but most less intrusive one. I read it somewhere, but I have forgotten the URL of original post, so if someone can point that out,
Here it is:

```
var control = 0;

function sendLoadMoreProductsRequest(url) {
control = 1;
new Ajax.Request(url, {
    onSuccess: function(response) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = response.responseText;
        $$('.pages')[0].innerHTML = $(div).select('.pages')[0].innerHTML;
        $$('.category-products')[0].innerHTML += $(div).select('.category-products')[0].innerHTML;
        jQ('#load-more-products').css('display','none');
        if(!$(div).select('.next.i-next')[0]){
            control = 1;
        }
        else{
        control = 0;
        }
    }
});}var callbackFunc= function() {
if($$('.next.i-next')[0]){
    var nextPageUrl = $$('.next.i-next')[0].readAttribute('href');
    sendLoadMoreProductsRequest(nextPageUrl);
}
else{
}}jQ(window).on( "scroll" , function() {if($$('.next.i-next')[0]){if(control === 0){
 var $document = jQ(document);
 var $window = jQ(this);

 if( $document.scrollTop() >= $document.height() - $window.height() - 1200 ) {
     callbackFunc();
     jQ('#load-more-products').css('display','block');}}}});if(!$$('.next.i-next')[0]){$('load-more-products').style.display = "none";}
```

It works with prototype library perfectly. Your are definitely gonna wanna adjust some of the hard coded parameters. In my case, I was having 12 products per page.
One more thing, for the sake of styling, you will be required to adjust the display of your toolbar to none, or you will have multiple toolbars in one page as the page scrolls to bottom.

P.S. My code formatting is too bad so if someone can adjust it a little bit, that'd be great.

JQ is my noconflict variable for jQuery, as $ is reserved for prototype. If you are not using jQuery, it can be easily customised to native javascript as well.